# Terminating With Uncaught Exception - Swift 2 Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, swift2

I am using Parse for my databases, and I just updated the parse SDKs and Xcode to version 7 with swift 2. However, now I am getting an error when the query below starts. The problem starts at the "findobjectsinbackground" part as the "third" print is not seen. Any ideas?

The Error:

> 2015-09-22 09:57:45.247 MyProject[456:133409] *** Terminating app due
>   to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:
>   'This query has an outstanding network connection. You have to wait
>   until it's done.'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x275d386b 0x38f86dff 0x275d37b1 0x638ac9 0x638b41 0x639bf9 0x6397bb 0x6399bf 0x2b5e78 0x2b4e94 0x2b5154
>   0x2b6e56ab 0x2b79fe97 0x2b79fd91 0x2b79f135 0x2b79ed8f 0x2b79e9dd
>   0x2b79e957 0x2b6e16bb 0x2afad67d 0x2afa8d79 0x2afa8c09 0x2afa8129
>   0x2afa7deb 0x2b6d860d 0x275960f1 0x275943e7 0x27594825 0x274e71e9
>   0x274e6fdd 0x3078baf9 0x2b74c18d 0x5fa6f4 0x396b1873) libc++abi.dylib:
>   terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

```
        followArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
    followArray2.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)


        let followQuery = PFQuery(className: "follow")
        followQuery.whereKey("user", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)
        followQuery.whereKey("followAproval", equalTo: 1)
        followQuery.addDescendingOrder("createdAt")

        var myObjects = [PFObject]()

        followQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

        myObjects = objects!

            for object in myObjects {

                self.followArray.append(object.objectForKey("userToFollow") as! String)

            }

         }
        }


        var myObjects2 = [PFObject]()

        let generalQuery = PFQuery(className: "tweets")
        generalQuery.addDescendingOrder("createdAt")
        generalQuery.limit = 100

        followQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

            myObjects2 = objects!

        for object in myObjects2 {

            self.followArray2.append(object.objectForKey("userName") as! String)

             }
          }
        }
```

Comment: What other code do you have after this?

Comment: You need to resolve objects as a variable first before iterating through it I think. Because since your task is async it can change as your iterating through it...

Comment: I added the other code after this

Comment: In the second query I wrote the first query's name at some point, that seems to be the reason. Sorry for taking your time. I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I think since your task is async, `objects` can actually change as you're iterating through it. I suggest you resolve it first as a variable. From your code:

```
print("second")

var myObjects = PFObject()

followQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (objects:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

    print("third")

    if error == nil {
        myObjects = objects 
    }
}

for object in myObjects! {

    self.followArray.append(object.objectForKey("userToFollow") as! String)

}
```

Comment: hello, I made the changes but still the error. I added the next code after this.

Comment: I guess I writed the first queries name in the second query, thats the reason. Completely my fault. Fixed it. Sorry for that.